# How could an AI interpret the requests of a human without the human needing to specify every detail?

Tags: natural-language-processing, agi, computational-linguistics, ai-completeness

Let the *request* be the thing that we asked the AI to do, not necessarily using *[commands](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/the-complete-list-of-siri-commands/)*.

Nowadays, we have our personal AI in our devices: Siri by Apple, Cortana by Microsoft, and so on. Most times, when we ask them to do certain tasks, they do the tasks for us. However, their action is based on the list of *commands*. When they don't clearly recognize the commands in our request, they suggest us to use certain commands. It is clear that there are limits to our choices (requests).

So, let's suppose that we have an AI that can interpret requests. There may not be *commands* in our request. AI is fully able to do anything in order to do what it is asked for. Basically, I am talking about an independent AI.

Now, consider the scenario where an AI is asked to clean the room. AI is allowed to throw away garbage, and move unnecessary (or unused) stuff into the storage.

This is the list of things that were in the room at the moment:

- A stained blanket
- Various decorations
- A dead clock on the wall
- Various unused items in the desk drawer
- A lost Airpod under the bed
- A sleeping cat in the bed

In this condition

1. Is washing a stained blanket a part of cleaning?
2. How can AI tell if anything is in use? Are decorations in use?
3. Would dead clock that only needs battery replacement considered garbage?
4. Would items in the desk drawer be included in AI's to-be-cleared list?
5. Would AI be able to recognize the difference between unused and lost?
6. What would happen to the poor cat?

Since there are many holes in the scenario and questions, I would like to know how the answers are derived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the problem of [commonsense knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonsense_knowledge_(artificial_intelligence)). It is [AI-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete).

If we knew how to solve it, Siri and Cortana wouldn't be as limited as they are.